# Allow users to manage dependency version of an npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, three.js, node-modules

I'm building a module that will have THREE.js as a dependency. I'm trying to work out the best way to include THREE as a dependency and make it accessible to the module and users of the module (users will need access to the THREE library within their projects). There are two ways I have figured out of making this work:

**One:**

Add THREE as a dependency of the module, import the whole library in the module and add it as a global variable like so:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'; 
window.THREE = THREE;
```

The disadvantage here is that I am responsible for what version of THREE is used, and also that the whole library is imported (THREE has recently switched to a modular build so it is no longer neccessary to include the whole library).

**Two:**

Add THREE as a dependency of the module **and** require users to add it as a dependency of their project. The idea here is that I can now import only what I need from the project:

```
import { Scene, Camera } from 'three';
```

And users can import what they need in their project, resulting in smaller file size.

The problem here is that now there are two copies of THREE installed, which are potentially different and incompatible versions. Is there any way to point my module to the top level module so that they can manage the version of THREE that is installed?

Comment: What I ve seen in cases similar to you, is making the user responsible for passing to the dependency to your module. On your side, you use the `three.js` they gave you, if they forgot to add a module you need, you return a error.

Comment: Just looking into this now, however I'm drawing a blank as to how to pass a dependency to a module. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Simple way: expose a "init" function, that take a parameter, which you put as a global var in your module, and use elsewhere as if it were the library. Else, you should be able to get parameters from the require itself, by setting the whole `module.exports` as a function, and use the parameter as the library.

Answer (score 1):

The way I ve seen it done is similar to this, but I never had to do something like it in production, so I do not know personally of its strength:

main.js:

```
'use strict';
const three = require('three'),
    mod = require('yourModule');

mod.init(three);
//...
```

yourModule.js:

```
'use strict';
let three = {};
function init(t) {
    three = t;
}
//...
modules.export = {
    init: init
    //...
};
```

Or

main.js:

```
'use strict';
const three = require('three'),
    mod = require('yourModule')(three);
```

yourModule.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (three) => {
    //...
};
```

Comment: Thank you - I ended up solving this in a much simpler way that seems pretty obvious in hindsight. Just load three before my module:
```import THREE from 'three'```
then
```window.THREE = THREE```
Then I load my module and the global variable is available. 
Thank you for your suggestions though, I was not aware that module.exports could be a function.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think the answer is correct and helpful for you, you can mark it as accepted. You can also post your own answer describing how you solved the problem, and accept it. It is not frown upon, and even encouraged if your answer is better than existing ones. It also remove the question from the "unanswered" list, that a lot of people browse in search of question that have no useful answer.